# mpirun on CPUs with specified IDs

Tags: centos, mpi, mvapich2

Does anyone know how to execute mpirun on specified CPUs? Though "mpirun -np 4 " specifies the number of CPUs used, what I here want to do is to specify CPU IDs.

The OS is CentOS 5.6 and MVAPICH2 is used on a single node with 6x2 cores.

Thank you for your cooperation.

Answer (score 2):

Yes; new versions of mvapich2 use the [hwloc](http://www.open-mpi.org/projects/hwloc/) library to enable CPU affinity and binding.

From the [User Guide](http://mvapich.cse.ohio-state.edu/support/user_guide_mvapich2-1.8_alpha1_p1.html#x1-530006.3.2):

> For example, if you want to run 4 processes per node and utilize cores
>   0, 1, 4, 5 on each node, you can specify:
>
> `$ mpirun_rsh -np 64 -hostfile hosts MV2_CPU_MAPPING=0:1:4:5 ./a.out`
>
> or
>
> `$ mpiexec -n 64 -f hosts -env MV2_CPU_MAPPING 0:1:4:5 ./a.out`
>
> In this way, process 0 on each node will be mapped to core 0, process
>   1 will be mapped to core 1, process 2 will be mapped to core 4, and
>   process 3 will be mapped to core 5. For each process, the mapping is
>   separated by a single “:”.